# Splash Screen API android apply change unpredictably

Tags: android, kotlin, android-theme, gradle-kotlin-dsl, android-splashscreen

When I try to make changes to the splash screen and reinstall the application, the splash does not change.

It's strange that sometimes (the next day) changes are picked up on the first build. It`s really magic that splash stay the same when I change color and reinstall app.

I am debugging on ZTE Benefit M8 Android 7.1.2 (custom firmware).

`app module`->`res folders`:

1. values/splash_theme.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.App.Starting1" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#069056</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">1000</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.NextTheme</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

1. values-night/splash_theme.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.App.Starting1" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#ff1212</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">1000</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.NextTheme</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name="myApp.app.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity
            android:name="myApp.presentation.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting1">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

`build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    id(Dependencies.Plugins.application)
    id(Dependencies.Plugins.kotlin)
    id(Dependencies.Plugins.kapt)
    id(Dependencies.Plugins.serialization)
    id(Dependencies.Plugins.parcelize)
}

android {
    namespace = Config.Namespace.App
    compileSdk = Config.Sdk.compile

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = Config.applicationId
        minSdk = Config.Sdk.min
        targetSdk = Config.Sdk.target
        versionCode = Config.Versions.code
        versionName = Config.Versions.name
      
        testInstrumentationRunner = Config.Test.instrumentationRunner
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = Config.Release.minifyEnabled // false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile(Config.Release.Proguard.name),
                Config.Release.Proguard.rules
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = Config.Kotlin.Options.jvmTarget
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(project(":core"))
    implementation(project(":core-ui"))

    implementation(Dependencies.Default.core)
    implementation(Dependencies.Default.appCompat)
    implementation(Dependencies.Default.material)

    //Activity
    implementation(Dependencies.Lifecycle.activity)

    //Fragment
    implementation(Dependencies.Lifecycle.fragment)

    // ViewModel
    implementation(Dependencies.Lifecycle.viewModel)

    // Lifecycle
    implementation(Dependencies.Lifecycle.lifecycle)
    kapt(Dependencies.Lifecycle.lifecycleCompiler)

    //Splash
    implementation(Dependencies.splash) // androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0
    ...
}
```

`MainActivity.kt`

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        installSplashScreen()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        getAppComponent().inject(this)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            .apply { setContentView(root) }
```

I try: invalid cache, restart, rebuild, clean, reinstalling dependencies by ./gradlew, reopen studio, delete app on device, rename splash theme, reconnect device with usb.

Comment: OK. What you may encounter if you use Google's New Splash Api.
In my case, I made a splash (code above). Then I decided to change its color and when restarting it did not change.
As a result, it turned out that rebooting the smartphone, every time the color in the splash changed, led to the result I needed and the color changed.

Comment: Also, given the fact that the next day on the first build I also saw changes, then:
1. Resources for the splash are somehow stored on the device.
2. Resources are updated when the smart is restarted or timeout.

I still don't know what in custom firmware or vendor api leads to this. However, I am inclined to believe that the problem is not in Android, but in the interaction of the New Splash API with the firmware / vendor api.
If someone can explain what's wrong, I would be grateful, thanks.